# Will the NuGet Package for developing Wndows Phone 8 work on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I'm trying to install a NuGet package named "amcharts", but everytime on the installation it gives the following error.

Tried to install using power-shell

[image]

I use Visual studio 2013 update 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried looking for that specific NuGet package and what I found is this:

[image]

Seems like it only supports WPF, Silverlight and Windows Phone 7. Also it was published in 2011, so most likely it doesn't even support Windows 8.

Comment: thanx mate. I was trying to use it on wp 8.1, but i was supposed to use silverlight to target wp8.